# Spring Boot map URL request to a Static Resource, not serving index.html by default

Tags: java, spring, angular, rest, spring-mvc

I have a **spring boot** app serving angular resources in my static [resources/static] folder. I also am using the same project to serve my JSON-REST-API endpoints.

Hence I have defined my REST api under localhost:9090/api/...
My Angular2 app-build is served under localhost:9090/ui/... via static resources

Now I want to forward all my ui/** urls to ui/index.html/**
How do I do this?

P.S. I have introduced a custom static resource url pattern
`spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/ui/**`
Then all my ui/** request will look to the static/**
This way I was able to secure my /api/** and "permitAll" ui/** requests

Answer (score 1):

This simple configuration will do the trick and will even refresh your # routes in angular 2 if enabled.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/ui").setViewName("forward:/ui/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/ui/").setViewName("forward:/ui/index.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }


}
```

Pointers:
 - @SpringBootApplication should be annotated where the spring boot app is run
 - Do not have @EnableWebMvc as this breaks all auto configuration done by spring boot
 - See whether this configuration is under a directory you have marked for
   @ComponentScan({"com.foo.config"})
 - This implementation is specifically tailored for situations where you have a custom spring.mvc.static-path-pattern defined [ui/]